# How to find a file with an certain string inside the content of the file by scanning a whole directory using grep

Tags: bash, grep

How would you use `grep` to find a file inside a directory that contains a certain string inside it's content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like:

```
grep -lR string directory/*
```

`-l` will print only the filename instead of content. `-R` will do it recursively. If you need to do it only in "directory" remove `-R`

```
grep -l string directory/*
```

Comment: You might want to refrain from answering questions which are common FAQs. They usually have a number of duplicates with multiple answers, many of which contain information which isn't in yours.